# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a premeasure

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu: \mathcal{F} \to [0, \infty]$ be a function on an algebra
>   $\mathcal{F}$ which satisfies $\mu(\emptyset) =0$, finite additivity, and for any collection
>   $\{A_n\}_{n =1}^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $A_n \subset
>  A_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \in
>  \mathcal{F}$, $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\lim_{n \to
>  \infty}\mu(A_n)\text{.}$$

I wish to show that $\mu$ is a premeasure and have only left to show countable additivity.

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{F}$ and let $C_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$ for all $n \geq 1$. Because of closure under finite unions in $\mathcal{F}$, we know $C_n \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $n \geq 1$. We also know that $C_n \subset C_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

So I am trying to show countable additivity of $\mu$: namely, 
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_j)\text{.}$$
Observe that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$$
and thus
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(C_n)$$
by assumption. But this book I have also says that
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j) $$
follows from finite additivity. This doesn't make sense to me. When I try to work out the details, I have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(C_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j \right) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j)$$
by finite additivity. I must have done something wrong, since I don't see how I get $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j)$ from this.

The only way I could see that step working is if $$\mu\left(\lim_{N \to \infty}\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}A_j\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}A_j \right)$$
which if it is true, has not yet been proven in this text. I have not been given anything about measures other than the definition.

Comment: I don't get this at all. Evidently you really mean $\mathcal F$ is an algebra, not a $\sigma$-algebra. But then $\mu$ _can't_ be a measure, by definition. ???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Doesn't the closure of countable unions imply $\sigma$ algebra?

Comment: You have $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(C_n)$$ 
And you know that $$C_n= \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j $$ where the $A_j$ are disjoint. So we have $$\mu(C_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j) $$ and then we have $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(C_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j) $$

Comment: @Ramiro Please feel free to post that as an answer so that I can award points.

Comment: @AndresMejia Closure under countable unions __would_ show it's a $\sigma$-algebra. There's nothing in the post to indicate that $\mathcal F$ _is_ closed under countable unions. The problem says if we have $A_n$ _such_ _that_ the union is in $\mathcal F$ then etc.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I didn't put the definition of a measure in my post from my textbook. It is defined over an algebra rather than a $\sigma$-algebra (as in the conventional definition) and satisfies countable additivity, has range $[0, \infty]$, and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by countable additivity, exactly? If the algebra is not a $\sigma$-algebra then "countable additivity" is impossible, by the usual definition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, I see what you're saying here. A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions, whereas an algebra isn't necessarily. The countable additivity condition for a measure states "for any disjoint collection of sets $A_1, A_2, \dots, \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \in \mathcal{F}$, $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\text{."}$$

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense. You should _really_ edit the post to clarify all this, because the terminology you're using is very non-standard, and hence the post as it is looks like nonsense to anyone not familiar with your private language. In fact what you're calling a measure is usually called a "premeasure" - called that because a premeasure on an algebra extends to an actual measure on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the algebra.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I'm very new to measure theory so I had no idea. I'll edit the post.

Comment: If I'm not missing anything you still need to change "Let $A_n$ be a sequence of disjoint sets..." at the start of the attempted proof  to "Let $An$ be a sequence of disjoint sets such that the union is in $\mathcal F$ and..."

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There are books that use the term "measure" to refer to a premeasure.  In such context, countably additive always  means countable additive on family of set whose union are in the domain of the "measure" .  Check, for instance, Halmos Measure Theory, chapter 2 section 7, (Measure on Rings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(C_n)$$
And you know that
$$C_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j$$
where the Aj are disjoint. So we have
$$\mu(C_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j)$$
and then we have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\right) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(C_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j)$$